# How long JavaScript file can be in practice?

Tags: javascript

I know this must be a silly question, but when those who create web browsers implement JavaScript and other parts, they should have some number in their mind, how big they expect the JavaScript file to be practically?

Of course modularity is good, but sometimes you just need something big. Especially machine-generated. And single file is seemingly faster to download and probably have a longer live in cache.

Some of my programs in other languages grow over 30K lines in single file, and I used to think that JavaScript is just about tiny files to handle `onClicks`. But now as big companies create huge apps, like spreadsheets or image editors, I wander how big the single file could be. What limits the size?

Comment: I don't have an answer for question, but don't forget you can minify your javascript!

Comment: If you have files in ANY languages that are 30k lines long, you are doing things wrong. a couple hundred is even really large. You should learn to separate your concerns. IE, you have `http://example.com/products` and `http://example.com/images` if your JavaScript, or any other language, deals ONLY with the products, keep it in a separate file. You can go even further with that.

Comment: When deploying, it should be a single compressed file. During development, you should split up your code into logical files like you do with any other language.

Comment: If you interpret "in practice" as "what is practical" then it depends on the user's network connection speed, patience and CPU processing power, in roughtly that order. Some trivial pages are 3mb with maybe 20 separate script files (plus all the other paraphernalia) and take maybe 15 seconds to download over a 1Mb connection. Is that practical?

Answer (score 1):

there is actually no file size limit besides from your own computer resources

Comment: really? my computer has 2TB HDD and 8GB RAM, so how long the JS file can be?

Comment: i think normaly about 3GB of your RAM will be used, so you have 5 GB left, which is 5,368,709,120 bytes, so your file could contain about 5,000,000,000 characters

Answer (score 0):

As I know there isn't any limit to it.
The only limit is how much your CPU / RAM can handle?

Comment: Is that a question or an answer?

Comment: Network connection speed might be a factor, regardless of CPU grunt.